# How to make Hibernate, JBoss and Eclipse work together in unit tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

I recently started working on related JBoss EAR, WAR and EJB projects (JBoss 7.7.1). Developers are using Eclipse for development and we launch JBoss and debug through Eclipse.

I can launch our webapp in Eclipse/JBoss with no problems.

Given that we have no tests at all I decided to start setting up a test environment, initially just to test the EJB project only.  But when trying to launch tests, I'm having lots of difficulty with configuration (I've looked all over and seen similar questions, but nothing has worked for me).

The project structure looks like:

```
ccc-ejb/
    src/
        ccc/
            <packages and classes under here>
        META-INF/persistence.xml
    test/
        ccc/
            <packages and classes under here>
            TestDatabase.java
```

Just for completeness (even though the file is still not being read) my persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="ccc">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasource/ccc-ds</jta-data-source>
    <class>ccc.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />    
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

As a very beginning to getting a test environment setup I have the following test class just to sanity check the environment:

```
public class TestDatabase { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
      System.out.println(System.class.getResource("META-INF/persistence.xml"));
      System.out.println(Class.forName("org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"));

      EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory  = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ccc");
      EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

      entityManager.close();
      entityManagerFactory.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }
  }
}
```

Output of this is:

```
/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/hibernate/main/hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:/Development/workspace-ccc-dev/ccc-ejb/build/classes:/Development/workspace-ccc-dev/ccc-ejb/lib/json_simple-1.1.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/activation/api/main/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/annotation/api/main/jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/ejb/api/main/jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/el/api/main/jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/enterprise/api/main/cdi-api-1.0-SP4.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/enterprise/deploy/api/main/jboss-jad-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/faces/api/main/jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/inject/api/main/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/interceptor/api/main/jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/jms/api/main/jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/jws/api/main/jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/mail/api/main/mail-1.4.4.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/management/j2ee/api/main/jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/persistence/api/main/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/resource/api/main/jboss-connector-api_1.6_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/rmi/api/main/jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/security/auth/message/api/main/jboss-jaspi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/security/jacc/api/main/jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/servlet/api/main/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/servlet/jsp/api/main/jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/servlet/jstl/api/main/jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/transaction/api/main/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/validation/api/main/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/ws/rs/api/main/jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/wsdl4j/api/main/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/xml/bind/api/main/jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/xml/registry/api/main/jboss-jaxr-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/xml/rpc/api/main/jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/xml/soap/api/main/jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/javax/xml/ws/api/main/jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/hibernate/validator/main/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/as/controller-client/main/jboss-as-controller-client-7.1.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/dmr/main/jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider/main/resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.2.Final-jandex.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider/main/resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.2.Final-jandex.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final-jandex.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider/main/resteasy-multipart-provider-2.3.2.Final-jandex.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider/main/resteasy-multipart-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/modules/org/jboss/ejb3/main/jboss-ejb3-ext-api-2.0.0.jar
null
class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate
```

Questions:

1. The project is configured in Eclipse as an EJB project and because of that automatically has a lot of JBoss jars and JBoss modules jars put on the build path (including Hibernate jars). However, hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar is not automatically added and I needed to add it myself. If I don't manually add it, then org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence will not be found. Curious as to why this jar is not automatically included like the other jar files?
2. The output for the persistence.xml resource is null? It's not being found. How can I fix this?

When Eclipse builds, it puts all the classes here:

```
/Development/workspace-ccc-dev/ccc-ejb/build/classes
```

This directory is definitely on the classpath from the output of the println above. Further, in the classes directory, in particular I can see:

```
classes/ccc/TestDatabase.class
classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Why isn't the persistence.xml file being picked up?

1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate doesn't look good either. I'll get to this when I get 1 and 2 fixed, but any hints here would also be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't the persistence.xml file being picked up?

Because the path to load it is wrong. It should be

```
System.class.getResource("/META-INF/persistence.xml")
```

Without the leading slash, the path is interpreted as relative to the package of the System class. With the leading slash, it starts at the root of the classpath.

Regarding the other questions, I don't know. But I don't see why anything should be "automatically" added to the build path. If you need a jar in the build path, add it to the build path. I don't see why that would be a problem.

Comment: Ah, yes thanks for the heads up, I completely missed that. What I meant be things be 'automatically' added to the build path, is that in Eclipse you need to associate a JBoss Runtime Environment to the EJB project. Once you do this, a bunch of jars are 'automatically' added to both the build path and runtime classpath. I say automatic, because Eclipse seems to decide which modules, jars, etc are added. Not all of the jars needed during runtime are added. How Eclipse decides which JBoss jars and modules to add seems 'automatic' or better yet 'automagic'.